# How to increase request timeout in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

How to increase request timeout in IIS 7.0? The same is done under application tab in ASP configuration settngs in IIS 6.0. I am not able to find the asp.net configuration section in IIS 7.0

Answer (score 217):

Add this to your Web Config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx

> Optional TimeSpan attribute.
>
> Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to
>   execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.
>
> This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False. To help to prevent shutting down the application
>   while you are debugging, do not set this time-out to a large value.
>
> The default is "00:01:50" (110 seconds).

Comment: Can this be set from the IIS 7 Manager GUI?

Comment: The timeout is specified in seconds, the default is 110 seconds. Note: This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the <compilation> element is set to false!

Comment: @Jowen: You rock! I had earlier changed debug to false days ago and didn't associate it with all the timeout errors I'd been receiving. Now I know.

Comment: Note that the maximum value of executionTimeout is also the max value of TimeSpan (10675199.02:48:05.4775807) which is... more then you need

Answer (score 87):

In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to **Manage Web** **Site** -> **Advanced Settings**. Under **Connection Limits** option, you should see **Connection Time-out**.

Comment: Is this same as request timeout. I am trying to migrate data from an xml document and the reuqest timesout. So if I increase the connection timeout will this be resolved.

Comment: i dont think this is correct, if 'HTTP Keep-Alive' is enabled, then this timing setting applies to it, meaning how long the connection will keep alive, i dont think this is related to 'request timeout' (how long iis waits for execution of a page)..

Comment: I think this is the right answer in certain situations, such as uploading a large file.  While waiting to upload, the

Comment: I have just checked this on a site hosted in IIS 7, it is set to 480s and an upload script ran 
 from a request for over 700s, so I don't think this is the right option.

Answer (score 59):

To Increase request time out add this to web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

and for a specific page add this

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The default is 90 seconds for .NET 1.x.

The default 110 seconds for .NET 2.0 and later.

Comment: You've earned the +1 with the information about the location

Comment: I think there is a typo in this answer as the default seems to be configured as 120 seconds for me

Answer (score 37):

Below are provided steps to fix your issue.

1. Open your IIS
2. Go to "**Sites**" option.
3. Mouse right click.
4. Then open property "**Manage Web Site**".
5. Then click on "**Advance Settings**".
6. Expand section "**Connection Limits**", here you can set your "**connection time out**"

[image]

Comment: link for more information:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/e1f13641(v=vs.80)

Comment: connection time out != request timeout

Comment: increase - database time out as well

Answer (score 32):

In IIS >= 7, a `<webLimits>` section has replaced `ConnectionTimeout`, `HeaderWaitTimeout`, `MaxGlobalBandwidth`, and `MinFileBytesPerSec` IIS 6 metabase settings.

Example Configuration:

```
<configuration>
   <system.applicationHost>
      <webLimits connectionTimeout="00:01:00"
         dynamicIdleThreshold="150"
         headerWaitTimeout="00:00:30"
         minBytesPerSecond="500"
      />
   </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

For reference: more information regarding these settings in IIS [can be found here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/weblimits). Also, I was unable to add this section to the web.config via the IIS manager's "configuration editor", though it did show up once I added it and searched the configuration.

Comment: This replaces `ConnectionTimeout`, not httpRuntime's `executionTimeout`.

Answer (score 11):

I know the question was about ASP but maybe somebody will find this answer helpful.

If you have a server behind the IIS 7.5 (e.g. Tomcat). In my case I have a server farm with Tomcat server configured.
In such case you can change the timeout using the IIS Manager:

- go to **Server Farms** -> **{Server Name}** -> **Proxy**
- change the value in the **Time-out** entry box
- click **Apply** (top-right corner)

or you can change it in the cofig file:

- open *%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config*
- adjust the server *webFarm* configuration to be similar to the following

Example:

```
<webFarm name="${SERVER_NAME}" enabled="true"> 
  <server address="${SERVER_ADDRESS}" enabled="true">
    <applicationRequestRouting httpPort="${SERVER_PORT}" />
  </server>
  <applicationRequestRouting>
    <protocol timeout="${TIME}" />
  </applicationRequestRouting>
</webFarm>
```

The **${TIME}** is in **HH:mm:ss** format (so if you want to set it to 90 seconds then put there 00:01:30)

In case of Tomcat (and probably other servlet containers) you have to remember to change the timeout in the *%TOMCAT_DIR%\conf\server.xml* (just search for **connectionTimeout** attribute in **Connector** tag, and remember that it is specified in **milliseconds**)

Comment: Please note that you should only post answers that are directly related to the question asked. Since this question is purely about IIS, an answer with information on Tomcat really is not relevant.

Comment: In this case I think the answer is relevant as the use case specified here (using IIS Application Request Routing to route to another server) is about IIS. The setting here is configurable inside IIS Manager as well. FWIW, this answer helped me troubleshoot just which request timeout I should change. (Since there are lots of timeout settings in IIS Manager)

Answer (score 4):

**Use the below Power shell command to change the execution timeout (Request Timeout)**

> Please note that I have given this for default web site, before using
>   these please change the site and then try to use this.

```
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.web/httpRuntime" -name "executionTimeout" -value "00:01:40"
```

**Or,  You can use the below C# code to do the same thing**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {

        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("Default Web Site");

            ConfigurationSection httpRuntimeSection = config.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime");
            httpRuntimeSection["executionTimeout"] = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:40");

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Or, you can use the JavaScript to do this.**

```
var adminManager = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager');
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site";

var httpRuntimeSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.web/httpRuntime", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site");
httpRuntimeSection.Properties.Item("executionTimeout").Value = "00:01:40";

adminManager.CommitChanges();
```

**Or, you can use the AppCmd commands.**

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.web/httpRuntime /executionTimeout:"00:01:40"
```

Comment: Why make such an effort?

Answer (score 3):

For AspNetCore, it looks like this:

```
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00">
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097433/request-timeout-from-asp-net-core-app-on-iis)