# Increasing timeout of ASMX webservices

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, asmx

I am running an ASMX webservice on IIS 7. The client is a silverlight application. I am issuing several asynchronous file requests to the webservice and processing them on AsyncCompleted. Sometime after all the async requests have been issued, I get the following timeout message. How can the timeout be increased.

I tried adding the following in the web.config of the ASP.NET project that is hosting my silverlight application.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="12000"/>
```

(This timeout is not happening when I do the requests synchronously, but synchronous operations are very slow.)

```
The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:5080/Service1.asmx' has exceeded the
allotted timeout.
```

Comment: [This is a related post and might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0)

Comment: Tried changing timeout under connection limit in IIS, but it is getting timeout before the timeout period that is set.

Comment: If you are using the latest IIS... why are you using the oldest service type? WCF (or WCF RIA) will give you far less trouble than ASMX. Is it a legacy service?

Answer (score 0):

See these sources:

- [Timeout error in WCF](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/55247/526302.aspx)
- [Silverlight Timeout Issues from WCF… exceeded the allotted timeout.](http://www.fredmastro.com/post/Silverlight-Timeout-Issues-from-WCFe280a6-exceeded-the-allotted-timeout.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the silverlight application i am in a doubt if my suggestion will work. 
Just try, to create the object of the webservice and then increase the time out value to what ever seconds you want. 
Below code may be helpful

```
 ConsoleApplicationFor2Groups.AdServices.ADService adser = new ADService();
 adser.Timeout = 100000; // this time is in milliseconds
```

Just let me know if this works.