# keep getting Event 1309 frequently

Tags: web-services, iis

i have a windows 2008 running web services. i keep getting this error frequently. soon the webservices gets timeouts and  and restart of the IIS seems to clear it. I need some help in diagnozing and getting root cause.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          7/14/2011 2:30:11 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MTRLPQDC217.bell.corp.bce.ca
Description:
Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted. 
Event time: 7/14/2011 2:30:11 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/14/2011 6:30:11 AM 
Event ID: 532e1f14b449406ea3fd6a3b744ff51d 
Event sequence: 12 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-129550968093856307 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\inetpub\wwwroot\GreenDay\ 
    Machine name: MTRLPQDC217 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7036 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Request timed out.



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://mtrlpqdc217:8085/wfaswebservice.asmx 
    Request path: /wfaswebservice.asmx 
    User host address: 142.117.237.106 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace: 


Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-07-14T06:30:11.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>19659</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>MTRLPQDC217.bell.corp.bce.ca</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3001</Data>
    <Data>The request has been aborted.</Data>
    <Data>7/14/2011 2:30:11 AM</Data>
    <Data>7/14/2011 6:30:11 AM</Data>
    <Data>532e1f14b449406ea3fd6a3b744ff51d</Data>
    <Data>12</Data>
    <Data>1</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-129550968093856307</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>D:\inetpub\wwwroot\GreenDay\</Data>
    <Data>MTRLPQDC217</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>7036</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP</Data>
    <Data>HttpException</Data>
    <Data>Request timed out.

</Data>
    <Data>http://mtrlpqdc217:8085/wfaswebservice.asmx</Data>
    <Data>/wfaswebservice.asmx</Data>
    <Data>142.117.237.106</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP</Data>
    <Data>7</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\GDA-SP</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs when the ASP.NET request executes for a period of time longer than the maximum timeout period allowed for server execution. You can fix this issue by changing the request execution timeout in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

Here are some resources that have already answered this problem,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2012/06/20/how-to-troubleshoot-httpexception-request-timed-out-asp-net-4-0-64-bit/

[How to increase request timeout in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis)