# BITS Upload response timeout

Tags: timeout, microsoft-bits

In our windows application we are using BITS Upload protocol (with upload-reply) to upload files to our server, treat them, and wait for a response.
Sometimes the server elaboration can be very long (>=10 minutes) and we encounter a timeout issue.

According to the document [http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/[MC-BUP].pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMC-BUP%5D.pdf)

> 3.1.2.2 Upload Response Timeout This timer limits the amount of time taken for receiving any of the responses mentioned in section 2.2 from
>   the server regardless of the state transitions involved. The default
>   value is 5 minutes; the legal range is any positive value.

Is there a way to change the default value of 5 minutes? How can I set it with an higher value?

Thanks.

Comment: So, the client is timing-out waiting for the server to respond.  Are you coding the server, or coding the client?  If the client, which API (if any) are you using?

Comment: I'm coding the client, with our proprietary language I can only drive BITS command using BITSADMIN.exe command line (it's grotty I know...) I can't use any API. In the meanwhile I probably found two solutions: - server side handle of the timeout - registry key to set to enlarge the timeout. I'm testing them...

Comment: I don't see how the server could handle it, unless it could send an HTTP header to the client suggesting how long it should wait.  However, it would seem from the doc that the timer is a private affair of the client.  Therefore the registry key would be the most likely option.  Are you sure you really want to use BITS as a request/response protocol though?  It would make more sense for the server to callback the client when done.  Five minutes is a pretty long idle time for the client to hold onto a session.

Comment: I can only use BITS I have no other option without rewrite everything :-( In a few hours I'll write the solution, it was a very long week to find it out! Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Shame you couldn't arrange it so that the server *immediately* returned a reply, which contained a time-estimate for when the 'reply' would be ready, and an identifier at which to fetch it.  Then your client could schedule a BITS download job later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried modifying some registry key (like `TimeQuantaLenght`), but it doesn't solve the issue.

To solve, first we enlarge the [`request timeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0) of the sites.

Second as reported in the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The server application must provide a response within five minutes. If
>   the server application does not reply within five minutes, the job
>   enters the transient error state. When the retry delay expires, the
>   BITS server will send another notification to the server application
>   (the server application should be written to handle duplicate
>   notifications).

so we handle the duplicate request! In case of `Transient Error` the BITS protocol try to restart the transfer after the time defined for `MinimunRetryDelay`.

We manage the issue by ourself; we identify each transfer with a GUID, if the transfered GUID entering the transient error state, and restart we check if the transfer was already happened and handle the corresponding action.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia, for upload jobs [BITS requires IIS web server with BIT server extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service#Technology):

> BITS version 1.0 supports only downloads. From version 1.5, BITS
>   supports both downloads and uploads. Uploads require the IIS web
>   server, with BITS server extension, on the receiving side.

I don't know how you are using the BITS protocol but, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362813.aspx) explains how to use the BITS Admin commnad-line tool to create download or upload jobs and monitor their progress. This switch below might help you:

> **/SetNoProgressTimeout** *Job Time-out*
>
> Sets the length of time, in seconds, that BITS tries to transfer the
>   file after the first transient error occurs.

and [this other page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes the BITS IIS Extension Properties. I quoted the one you might need.

> Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) uses an ISAPI to extend
>   IIS to support upload jobs. BITS uses these properties to determine
>   how to upload the files.
>
> **BITSSessionTimeout** Data type: **DWORD**
>
> Number of seconds the connection is maintained if no progress is made
>   uploading the file; the timer is reset when progress is made. BITS
>   closes the connection if the time-out is reached and cleans up data
>   associated with the session.

Comment: You may be able to use the IIS UI to Configure the Virtual Directory for BITS uploads. Select Properties from the context menu of the virtual directory. Press the BITS Extension tab to access the BITS properties page (the BITS server extension ISAPI must be installed). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363164(v=vs.85).aspx