# Asp.net with sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

While i am executing stored procedure via asp.net, application throws `connect timeout expire` exception.
But if i execute stored procedure through query window it executes successfully in 46 seconds.

Do you have any idea about the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeout value in the connection string, but to set timeout value for specific stored procedure to be executed, you can use the way suggested by @doterob

Check following links:

[Connection Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

[Command Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

**Edit:**

You might want to check out why it takes so much time to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: The default timeout if not supplied is 30 seconds, this would explain why your ASP.NET site is timing out, if the query takes 46 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The execution produces a timeout exception. You may change the timeout parameter

When you create de SqlCommand to execute stored procedure, you can put the timeout in seconds

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandTimeout = 100; //100 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code for checking How much time it is taking

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 100;(100 is in second)
```

by increasing CommandTimeout you can check.

Answer (score 0):

It may be *either* your `sql command execution times out` *or* your `web server times out`. Since you said it takes 46 seconds in SSMS, I think it is your web server timing out. I would suggest you to increase both time out values to suitable values.

For IIS you could use IIS Manager to do that. Here is [a good link for IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0)