# The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting this exception which happens every other time. For some reason I do not think its my code as it happens on different pages as well. It also happens on pages where I do not have the DateTime object.

In addition the exception window that comes up is different when there is an application exception which goes to a line of code. When this exception happens this is not the case. At the top it says the code stack only contains external code.

```
The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
 at System.DateTime.op_Addition(DateTime d, TimeSpan t)
 at System.Web.HttpContext.MustTimeout(DateTime utcNow)
 at System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.RequestTimeoutEntry.TimeoutIfNeeded(DateTime now)
 at System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.CancelTimedOutRequests(DateTime now)
 at System.Web.RequestTimeoutManager.TimerCompletionCallback(Object state)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
 at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
 at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
 at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

Comment: *For some reason I do not think its my code as it happens on different pages as well* It looks like IIS doing what it normally does and making sure that your request isn't taking longer than the timeout. Have you set the timeout to something like -1 or 999999999?

Comment: `web.config` and in other places.

Comment: For me that was the issue, timeout in the web.config was out of range. appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext.MustTimeout` seems to be [involved in coordinating request timeouts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/06/21/how-to-troubleshoot-httpexception-request-timed-out-asp-net-4-0-64-bit.aspx). To this end, I imagine that...

```
System.DateTime.op_Addition(DateTime d, TimeSpan t)
```

...is `MustTimeout` calculating the instant that a request should timeout. It could do this by adding some timeout value to the request's start time.

Check that you don't have any timeouts (in `web.config` or otherwise) that are artificially high or invalid. For example:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999999999" />
</system.web>
```

Various timeouts are documented [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis7-0).

Comment: I do have <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="300000000000" />
  but I want the site to not timeout as users upload files that take a while so I do not want the site to timeout. Also, am I missing something. If its too high then it should not timeout, right? so wht the exception then?

Comment: Your `executionTimeout` is about 9512 years. `DateTime` can represent up to the year `9999`. Add `2013` and `9512` together. IIS can't calculate exactly when the request should timeout. Try setting a timeout that's only 7 millenia long.

Comment: One more question. Is this timeout different than the session timeout, how do i set the other then. It seems this timeout is for loading the current request? and the other one I need to set is the one where the session expires.

Comment: There are several timeouts, for connections, requests, sessions (although only for `InProc` and other session state providers that support timeouts), cookies etc. I suggest you figure out which ones you use (you might use cookie-less sessions in which case cookie timeout doesn't matter) and then configuring them sensibly. [But the client browser might enforce its own timeouts, so if your file uploads take too long consider breaking them up](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same when i was trying to expires cookies, but now [its](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/10/the-added-or-subtracted-value-results.html) worked for me :)

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("appts");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Max Value 23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999,

Min Value  00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

If your DateTime + TimeSpan< MinValue  Or DateTime + TimeSpan>MaxValue
```

You will get the exception, make sure you remain in bounds.