# Limit max execution time on IIS 8.5 (Windows 2012 R2)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-8.5

I'm struggling to find good info on this one. In short, I'd like to reduce the "max execution time" of any requests against my asp.net application running on IIS 8.5. Older versions of IIS/asp.net had the "MaxExecutionTime" setting in web.config, however this doesn't seem to have any effect on my IIS 8.5. I've tried setting the following in web.config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3"/>
```

Which should (in theory) throw away any request running for more than 3 seconds. However, this setting has no effect.

My question: Is there any way to limit the execution time of an asp.net request outside of implementing stopwatches/timers in the code itself?

Comment: In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. In there, under Connection Limits you should see Connection Time-out. Hope this help you : )

Comment: Pretty sure this is not what I'm looking for. Connection time-out deals with keep-alive settings. What I need is to be able to kill requests that are executing for more than xx seconds (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis)