# ServiceStack based REST service gives timeout for log running process

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I need to run a 1-time long-running operation (around 10 minutes) via a ServiceStack service. I run this all on my local machine with ServiceStack running on IIS and .NET 5. Now it gives a timeout and I have no clue what is the cause (I also checked my IIS settings by the way). Part of my code (I removed some not relevant code):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var jsonServiceClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/services");
   jsonServiceClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
   await CorrectCreationDates(jsonServiceClient);
}

private static async Task CorrectCreationDates(JsonServiceClient jsonServiceClient)
{
   var request = new CorrectCreationDatesRequest();
   var result = await jsonServiceClient.PostAsync(request);
}
```

This is the exception:

System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
ServiceStack.AsyncServiceClient.SendWebRequestAsync(string, string, object, System.Threading.CancellationToken, bool) in AsyncServiceClient.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Gloneco.Importer.Program.CorrectCreationDates(ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient) in Program.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
...
[Call Stack Truncated]

Comment: 10 minutes is a long time for a web request. Should it be handled some other way?

Comment: I know, but it is also a test case: Are these kind of batch-like processes possible using REST services. But you are right I could reuse the repository logic in the console and skip the REST service layer. Another reason is I like to add later admin like services to a website which could take more time.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack doesn't impose any request limits itself, any limits are imposed by the underlying HTTP Server, e.g. if you're using IIS checkout the [How to increase request timeout in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis) answers.

Comment: Many thanks! I completely looked at the wrong place: I checked the application pools! Also because my REST services are configured as an application under the main website I could not find the timeout setting, but it was (of course) a setting of the main website.