# IIS URL REWRITE TIMEOUT IN 1 mins

Tags: node.js, axios, iis-10

Hello I have a question on IIS. I am using a node.js application in a window server.
Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8082/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have set in `server.setTimeout(1800000)`
However, I use axios to call in chrome.

```
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api',
  timeout: 5 * 1000 * 60
})
```

But I still get FAILED after one minutes in CHROME. What I need to add in IIS setting?

Comment: For setting Timeout in iis, you can refer to this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414441/how-to-increase-request-timeout-in-iis) But this is not necessarily a timeout problem, you need more error information to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: iis console (run inetmgr) -> rootnode (start page) -> (iis section) Application Request Routing Cache -> (on the right side) Server Proxy Settings -> Time-out